# How can I verify encryption for Platform Events?

Tags: platform-event, shield-encryption

Does Salesforce provide a way to check Shield Platform Encryption for Platform Events? I wanted to verify what type encryption is applied to Platform Events when encryption is enabled from Setup -> Quick Find -> Encryption Policy

Below statement gave me false:

```
System.debug('That is ' +sObjectType.Case_Events__e.fields.Event_Type__c.isEncrypted());
```

Answer (score 2):

The encryption is at rest and its at the database level which we don't have access to.

Check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_encryption.htm#platform_events_encryption_steps)

It does use the generated tenant secret to encrypt the data. If you still want to factually see encryption i guess you will have to contact salesforce support.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Event Bus is indeed using the generated tenant secret but not sure if it is the key for Probabilistic or Deterministic.